# Mutual authentication(SSL) setup Java stack (Production Cloud)

Tags: java, ssl, jakarta-ee, ssl-certificate

I want to setup mutual authentication on Tomcat 8.
I have done the setup of keys primarily keystore and truststore and the setup is working with Firefox tested.
When accessing the URL I am prompted for certificate and when appropriate certificate is provided I am allowed the access.

The piece of puzzle I am missing is, the truststore that I have which has CA cert and public keys of few clients. This CA should be a self signed CA, not from known authorities on the web, as.

> 1. I just do not want anybody to have access, people using my CA only should be able to access. Assuming say abc.com has certificate signed by authority godady or verisign, which are well known and trusted should not be able to call. I want strict access.
> 2. In my truststore I just want to keep CA no public keys, I do not want to keep adding certs as clients grow up. Clients would use my CA.

*I think my self signed CA in truststore and clients using my CA only in chain for their certificates should be good enough for secure(only clients with my CA) scalable solution, where I do not have to keep adding clients in truststore.*

Please advice my assumptions are correct for a production cloud based system.

Thanks for the time.

Comment: You are conflating authentication with authorization. TLS does the authentication, based on PKI. Authorization is an application  responsibility. You are making life hard for yourself by trying to combine these functions. All you have to do is have your application, or more probably your Web server, check the subject or the signer of the certificate to decide which if any roles he should be allocated.

Comment: @EJP thanks for the comment, yes in application layer there will be checks as you suggested identifying the user from certificate and authorizing him to parts of application, my only concern is with above setup, there should not be any holes in authentication, basically anyone with a certificate should not be able to call, I should be able to control certificates with my self CA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, your assumption are correct. During SSL handshake server will ask client to provide any certificate issued by CA present in server trust-store. Also you need to consider that client trust-store should have issuing CA of server certificate otherwise it will show untrusted server certificate on client/browser.

Comment: If I will have a CA certificate which is trusted by browser implies it is well known CA won't just anybody having certificate signed by that CA would be able to access. I want only certificates with my self signed certificate to be able to make a call, I understand there will be warning in browser, but that is not a concern. The service will be used by API, it is not user facing.

Comment: Okay then you can ignore warning. Usual practice is to provide issuing CA certificate(of server) to client so they can import this certificate and client will make sure whether server is trusted or not.